# IAP where I get paid?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have search with every word of my limited English for this question, and I think it's is not appropriate for this site but I just got to try.

I implemented Google IAP for Android. In all the tutorials I have read not one tells where I can check how much money I'm making, or specify where I get paid. I guess what I'm trying to ask is how Google is gonna pay me if I have not specified anything?

Answer (score 2):

Google's documentation on in-app billing is [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html). Note that

> No special account or registration is required other than a Google
>   Play Developer Console account and a Google Wallet merchant account.

The Wallet merchant account is how Google will pay you; the funds will be sent there when appropriate (when above the payment threshold set in your account, and on the monthly billing date, which I believe is the 15th of every month).

You can monitor your revenue from your developer console account dashboard, which will also provide you with downloadable financial reports regularly.